# Japanese characters in pdf bookmarks

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, japanese

I created a LaTeX document in Japanese and I compiled it using `pdflatex`. The document is generated correctly, but the bookmarks in the side panel of the PDF viewer do not show the Japanese characters, as shown in the picture below. I would like to find a solution to this problem (based on using `pdflatex`).

[image]

The LaTeX code I'm using is the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[whole]{bxcjkjatype}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{橋脚のソリッドモデル（Solid model of a pier）}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{解析モデル概要} 

この例題ではに示す橋脚のソリッドモデルを作成します。. 

\subsection{基礎と橋脚のジオメトリ作成} 
基礎および橋脚のためのシリンダー形状を作成します。

\subsection{梁のジオメトリ作成} 
最初に側面を定義しこれを押し出してソリッドとすることで、上端の梁を作成します。

\section{線形解析の実行} 
構造線形静的解析を実行します。この解析では、出力結果を含めてすべてデフォルトの設定を使用します。

\end{document}
```

It is interesting to note that the generated toc file has the section names with japanese characters:

```
\select@language {english}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}解析モデル概要}{1}{section.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}基礎と橋脚のジオメトリ作成}{1}{subsection.1.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2}梁のジオメトリ作成}{1}{subsection.1.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2}線形解析の実行}{1}{section.2}
```

However, there is the `\select@language{english}` command that probably compromises the use of Japanese characters in the side panel.

Comment: use the hyperref  `unicode` option to enable extended range of characters in pdf internal strings

Comment: @MarcelloM: In case David's suggestion wasn't sufficiently clear: you should load the `hyperref` package as follows: `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}`. :-) Moreover, you may also want to set the options `colorlinks` and `linktocpage`. Thus, try loading the package as `\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref}`.

Comment: Correct solution! Using the `unicode` option in the hyperref package allows me to have Japanese characters in the bookmarks. Thanks @DavidCarlisle and @Mico!