# Colouring only certain letters as a native property of the document

Tags: color, letters, japanese

I used a tool from Word to study Japanese, which enabled me to colour only certain characters of a lyric while listening to the music, the effectiveness of that was ridiculously powerful and I wish to mirror that with LaTeX so,

Instead of colouring each character あ I look for a way of doing all あ's in a document, which will be kinda big...

Comment: Please tell us which TeX engine you use -- pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX? Please also edit your posting to post a sample text block that could be used to test potential solutions. (Not everyone who can program up LaTeX has ready access to Japanese text...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use LuaLaTeX to typeset your document, you may achieve your formatting objective by setting up a Lua function that applies the desired per-character colorizing operations "on the fly". The crucial work is performed by the `unicode.utf8.gsub` function calls. Just place the characters you wish to colorize into the square-bracket parts ("character classes" in Lua terminology) in the second arguments of `unicode.utf8.gsub`.

The solution also provides two LaTeX macros, called `\ColorizeOn` and `\ColorizeOff`; they activate and deactivate the Lua function.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif CJK JP} % some suitable font

\usepackage{xcolor}  % for '\textcolor' macro
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment 

%% set up the main Lua function
\begin{luacode}
function colorize_selected_letters ( s )
  s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "[めリ脚]" , "\\textcolor{red}{%0}" )
  s = unicode.utf8.gsub ( s , "[すの義]" , "\\textcolor{blue}{%0}" )
  return s 
end
\end{luacode}

%% set up two LaTeX utility macros
\newcommand\ColorizeOn{\directlua{%
   luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", 
   colorize_selected_letters, "csl" )}}
\newcommand\ColorizeOff{\directlua{%
   luatexbase.remove_from_callback( 
   "process_input_buffer", "csl" )}}

\begin{document}
%% (the following text is "borrowed" [!] from  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437081/5001)
\ColorizeOn
\section{解析モデル概要} 

この例題ではに示す橋脚のソリッドモデルを作成します。. 

\subsection{基礎と橋脚のジオメトリ作成} 
基礎および橋脚のためのシリンダー形状を作成します。

\subsection{梁のジオメトリ作成} 
最初に側面を定義しこれを押し出してソリッドとすることで、上端の梁を作成します。

\ColorizeOff
\section{線形解析の実行} 
構造線形静的解析を実行します。この解析では、出力結果を含めてすべてデフォルトの設定を使用します。

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot hehe it worked just amazingly <3